# Assertion failed (queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescCollection[0].type()) in knnMatchImpl,

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

when using **BOWImgDescriptorExtractor** with **DescriptorExtractor** as **SIFT** and **DescriptorMatcher** as **ButeForce** i am getting error as

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescCollection[0].type()) in knnMatchImpl,

what could me my error.

when i am trying to compute 
eg.

> bowide->compute(img, keypoints, response_hist);

Comment: please put your more code related to BOW

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error using the Surf feature detector and extractor with BFMatcher.

The error occurs because the query descriptor mat and train descriptor mat doesn't have the same type - as stated in your error message.
This happened to me only when no keypoints for the train or query image could be calculated by the feature detector.
Check that the size of your keypoints vector is not zero before doing the matching.

Comment: yes.. this was happening for me. now I checked keypointts before checking matches and not giving that error

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error. There is another possible reason: the `dtype` of the dictionary should be `float32`. It turns out that I did some operations with the dictionary with numpy before calling the `setVocabulary` function, which changed the `dtype` of the dictionary implicitly.